# how can i fix undefined varriable in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-6

i wrote a code in my blade page in LARAVEL that can change them  dynamically by user .

i save css styles in cookie
and i defined css variable in my codes

but in main page i get this error :
Undefined index: css

my code :

```
 <?php
session_start();

$default = 'dark.css'; // define stylesheets
$darkcss = 'dark.css';
$lightcss = 'light.css';

$expire = time()+60*60*24*30; // how long to remember css choice (60*60*24*30 = 30 days)

if ( (isset($_GET['css'])) && ($_GET['css'] == $lightcss) ) { // set cookie for light css
    $_SESSION['css'] = $_GET['css'];
    setcookie('css', $_GET['css'], $expire);
}

if ( (isset($_GET['css'])) && ($_GET['css'] == $darkcss) ) { // set cookie for dark css
    $_SESSION['css'] = $_GET['css'];
    setcookie('css', $_GET['css'], $expire);
}

if ( (isset($_GET['css'])) && ($_GET['css'] == $default) ) { // set cookie for default css
    $_SESSION['css'] = $_GET['css'];
    setcookie('css', $_GET['css'], $expire);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['css'])) { // check for css stored in cookie
    $savedcss = $_COOKIE['css'];
} else {
    $savedcss = $default;
}

if ($_SESSION['css']) { // use session css else use cookie css
    $css = $_SESSION['css'];
} else {
    $css = $savedcss;
}

// the filename of the stylesheet is now stored in $css
echo '<link href="/admin/assets/css/'.$css.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
?>
```

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['css']) { // use session css else use cookie css` in this line u miss `isset` that's why u r getting error

Comment: yeah thanks it worked. but i cant approve your comment please resend your answer .@KamleshPaul

Comment: hey i added my answer please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### problem is here

`if ($_SESSION['css']) { // use session css else use cookie css`

in this line u miss `isset()` that's why u r getting error

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a path for cookies

```
setcookie('css', $_GET['css'], $expire, '/');
```